# How to determine continuity in higher dim

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1-\cos{\sqrt{xy}}}{y}$$

$$f(x,0) = \frac{x}{2}$$

How do I prove this is continuous in the quadrant $x,y \ge 0 $?

I can't find counterexamples (weak). I'm just starting working in higher dimensions and don't have a feel for the tricks here. Something about cosines always being continuous? Is there a rule in $\mathbb R^2$ like how polynomials in $\mathbb R$ are always continuous on their domain? What tricks should I instinctively be thinking of in a problem like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint.* You have, when $x \to 0$,$$\cos x=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)$$ giving $$\frac{1-\cos{\sqrt{xy}}}{y}=\frac{1-(1-xy/2+O(x^2y^2))}{y}=\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2y)$$ leading to the desired result.